# Rails shows wrong forum path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I made Forum model which belongs to Category and in show view of every category each forum from that category needs to be showed, but links are pointing at wrong paths (for example, in category 4 I have only one forum which points to *category/1/forum/1* and category 1 doesn't even exist).

One more note: each category has it's position field (integer) and they're sorted with that field in ascending order. Category 4 have position 1, but why would that number be on the place of category id in url?

When I try to access /category/4/forum/1 I get the error "Couldn't find Category with 'id'=1"

**CategoriesController**

```
class CategoriesController < ApplicationController

    def index
        categories_ordered
    end

    def new
        @category = Category.new
        categories_ordered
    end

    def create
        @category = Category.new(category_params)
        categories_ordered
        if @category.save
            redirect_to forums_path, notice: "Kategorija je uspešno kreirana."
        else
            render "new"
        end
    end

    def show
        find_category
        find_forums
    end

    def edit
        find_category
    end

    def update
        find_category

        if @category.update(category_params)
            redirect_to category_path(@category), notice: "Kategorija je uspešno ažurirana."
        else
            render "edit"
        end
    end

    def destroy
        find_category
        @category.destroy

        redirect_to forums_path, notice: "Kategorija je uspešno obrisana."
    end

    private

    def category_params
        params.require(:category).permit(:name, :description, :position)
    end

    def find_category
        @category = Category.find(params[:id])
    end

    def find_forums
        @forums = @category.forums.all
    end

    def categories_ordered
        @categories = Category.all.order("position ASC")
    end

end
```

**ForumsController**

```
class ForumsController < ApplicationController

    def new
        find_category
        @forum = @category.forums.new
    end

    def create
        @category = Category.find(params[:category_id])
        @forum = @category.forums.create(forum_params)
        if @forum.save
            redirect_to category_path(@category), notice: "Forum je uspešno kreiran."
        else
            render "new"
        end
    end

    def show
        find_category
        find_forum
    end

    def edit
        find_category
        find_forum
    end

    def update
        find_category
        find_forum
        if @forum.update(forum_params)
            redirect_to forum_path(@forum), notice: "Forum je uspešno ažuriran."
        else
            render "edit"
        end
    end

    private

    def forum_params
        params.require(:forum).permit(:title, :description)
    end

    def find_category
        @category = Category.find(params[:category_id])
    end

    def find_forum
        @forum = @category.forums.find(params[:id])
    end

end
```

**categories#show**

```
<% authorize %>

<h2><%= @category.name %></h2>

<p><%= @category.description %></p>

<div class="list-group">
    <% @category.forums.each do |f| %>
        <a href="<%= forum_path(f) %>" class="list-group-item">
            <h4 class="list-group-heading"><%= f.title %></h4>
            <p class="list-group-text">
                <%= f.description %>
            </p>
        </a>
    <% end %>
</div>

<% if is_admin? %>

    <%= link_to new_forum_path, class: "btn btn-primary" do %>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> Dodaj forum
    <% end %>

    <%= link_to edit_category_path(@category), class: "btn btn-primary" do %>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span> Izmeni
    <% end %>

    <%= link_to category_path(@category), class: "btn btn-danger", method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Da li ste sigurni da želite obrisati ovu kategoriju?" } do %>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span> Obriši
    <% end %>

<% end %>
```

**routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  root "welcome#index"

  get "start" => "welcome#index", as: "index"
  get "registration" => "users#new", as: "register"
  get "login" => "sessions#new", as: "login"
  post "login" => "sessions#create"
  get "logout" => "sessions#destroy", as: "logout"
  get "users" => "users#index", as: "users"
  post "users" => "users#create"
  get "profile" => "users#show", as: "profile"
  get "user/:id" => "users#show", as: "user"
  get "user/:id/edit" => "users#edit", as: "edit_user"
  patch "user/:id" => "users#update"
  delete "user/:id" => "users#destroy"

  get "categories/add" => "categories#new", as: "new_category"
  get "category/:id" => "categories#show", as: "category"
  patch "category/:id" => "categories#update"
  delete "category/:id" => "categories#destroy"
  get "category/:id/edit" => "categories#edit", as: "edit_category"

  get "terms" => "welcome#terms", as: "terms"
  get "wh" => "bugs#new", as: "wh"

  get "bugs" => "bugs#index", as: "bugs"
  post "bugs" => "bugs#create"
  get "bug/:id" => "bugs#show", as: "bug"
  delete "bug/:id" => "bugs#destroy"

  get "forum" => "categories#index", as: "forums"
  get "category/:category_id/forum/add" => "forums#new", as: "new_forum"
  get "category/:category_id/forum/:id" => "forums#show", as: "forum"
  get "category/:category_id/forum/:id/edit" => "forums#edit", as: "edit_forum"
  patch "category/:category_id/forum/:id" => "forums#update"
  delete "category/:category_id/forum/:id" => "forums#destroy"

  resources :users
  resources :sessions

  resources :categories do
    resources :forums
  end

  resources :bugs
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
end
```

Comment: Did you check your routes.rb file?? Please Post your config/routes.rb also.

Comment: @ChetanDatta Posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error is partially solved; I just had to use different parameters with **ForumsController** (*category_id* for categories and *id* for forums).

```
def find_category
    @category = Category.find(params[:category_id])
end

def find_forum
    @forum = @category.forum.find(params[:id])
end
```

And change forum routes accordingly.

It looks like problem still isn't solved. I changed this parts but I still have problems with URLs. Now category and forums IDs are mixed in url (instead of */category/4/forum/1* it shows */category/1/forum/4*).

**Edit:** Problem is finally solved! [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13434406/3102952) gave me an idea what I should do. I just had to specify @category with paths too (just changing two lines):

```
<div class="list-group">
    <% @category.forums.each do |f| %>
        <a href="<%= forum_path(@category, f) %>" class="list-group-item">
            <h4 class="list-group-heading"><%= f.title %></h4>
            <p class="list-group-text">
                <%= f.description %>
            </p>
        </a>
    <% end %>
</div>

<% if is_admin? %>

    <%= link_to new_forum_path(@category), class: "btn btn-primary" do %>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> Dodaj forum
    <% end %>
```